# Get updated rows without triggers or timestamps

Tags: mysql, data-synchronization

I'm working on a project with a client. The client has a MySQL Database with a few large tables (~100 million records each).
I've pulled the initial data.
I am required to sync the client's database to my database.
Now whenever the client inserts a row in any of the tables, I should sync it to my table. However, there are some (very strict) restrictions.
I cannot create triggers on client's tables.
The tables may not have a dateTime column for me to recognise the creation time of a row.
I do not wish to run a comparison between client's table vs mine(which will obviously take days just to identify a few 100 new insertions)

Is there any other way I can extract the newly inserted rows from client's tables?

Comment: Is there any reason you can't setup replication across the databases?

Answer (score 1):

Take a copy of the clients binary logs.  Act as if you're doing a disaster recovery.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/point-in-time-recovery.html

The relay log may be an alternative.